# How to use selenium to extract elements from expandable section

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, webdriver, java-stream, webdriverwait

I'm learning how to use selenium to **extract data from webpages**. The data I’m trying to extract from page https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1366-W-22nd-St-90007/home/6896268 is the date, e.g. **Oct 29, 2018**. All the dates are in the first column of a html table "Property History for 1366 West 22nd St".

However, with the following code, I can only get the **first three dates** from the table.

`cell = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@class="basic-table-2"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')`

Because the table is folded, I need to click the section bottom link **See all property history** link to unfold the table and see the rest of the dates in this table.  Is there anyway to use selenium to get all the dates from the table includes the dates in folded rows?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to click the "See all" link before you can get those dates.  They're simply not in the DOM until the list is expanded.  But clicking is easy:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'bottomLink').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

On the [website](https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1366-W-22nd-St-90007/home/6896268) to click on the element with text as **See all property history** to unfold the table and extract the dates from the table you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and then using **Java8**'s **`stream()`** and **`map()`** you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1366-W-22nd-St-90007/home/6896268");
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("section#property-history-scroll h2.h2"))));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.bottomLink"))).click();
  List<String> myDates = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("section#property-history-scroll tbody tr.PropertyHistoryEventRow[id^='propertyHistory-']>td.date-col"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList());
  System.out.println(myDates);
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [Oct 29, 2018, Aug 24, 2018, Aug 24, 2018, Jul 24, 2018, Mar 18, 2018, Dec 31, 2015, Sep 11, 2015, Jul 10, 2015, May 22, 2015, May 20, 1988, Aug 10, 1979]
  ```